# pypy not installing opencv

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, pypy

I want to use pypy to gain speed for a project I am doing and I need to use opencv and numpy but when trying to install opencv from pycharm interpreter settings I get the following error:

> Collecting opencv-python
>
> DEPRECATION: A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
>   ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   opencv-python (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution
>   found for opencv-python

how to install opencv to use with pypy?

Answer (score 2):

Since it is difficult to build OpenCV, they only upload binary wheels to PyPI (where `pip` goes to get packages). If you really want to use OpenCV on PyPy, you will have to compile from a github checkout of https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python. If you make any progress on this, please let the maintainer of that repo know, the best would be via a PR that explains how to successfully build. Then they could upload the binary packages to PyPI for PyPY.

Answer (score -1):

to install opencv you need to execute this command:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

ps : Use this commnad even if you want to use cv2

Hope I've helped you.

Comment: when trying what you suggested I get ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python

Comment: wich OS are you using ?

Comment: If you are using mac try intalling it with hombrew, if you are using linux try to install it with sudo apt-get install opencv-python

Comment: check you python version. I am using python3. But it should work even in python2

Comment: I am on Ubintu 18.04 and using pypy python implementation which is not the default cpython implementation so I think this why it is working for you but not me.. I think there is a catch